# Writing software for E-Book Reader Devices

Tags: c, linux, open-source, gcc, e-ink

Can you please recommend any E-Book Reader which can execute a third-party software, so that anybody can create software for such device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there's two I know of:

- The [OpenInkPot](http://openinkpot.org/) Linux distribution for e-reader devices, which works on a few e-ink readers (and should be ported to more as time goes on).  You shouldn't have much trouble writing third party software for that;
- The iRex DR1000.  Take a look at [this forum thread](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=37883) where someone has created a VMware image for doing development targetted at this e-reader.

Comment: Thank you! Now I will not ever buy Sony or Amazon devices.

Answer (score 1):

The Nook from Barnes and Noble has its system software installed on a removable 2GB micro SD card.  Since it runs Android, it should be easy to develop your own software for it.

Answer (score 1):

There's web based e-paper development platform thats offered by [Visionect](http://www.visionect.com). The devices are nice looking yet rugged and waterproof 6" e-paper tablets and the development documentation is fully available ([see docs.visionect.com](http://docs.visionect.com)).